# MyDataSet.Designer.cs throws {"There is no row at position 0."} even though I made sure there is data?

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, datarow, dataset-designer

This is the code snippet where the exception is thrown

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
    
        productCardTableAdapter.Fill(_MyInv_Data_DataSet.ProductCard);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
    if (_MyInv_Data_DataSet.ProductCard.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow r in _MyInv_Data_DataSet.ProductCard.Rows)
        {
            CustomCard c = new CustomCard();
            c._ID = int.Parse(r["ID"].ToString()); //the exception is thrown after this statement
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

you clearly see that I checked that the rows are not empty and the fact the error is thrown after entering the `foreach` statement is another proof as well.
the error is thrown in the `MyDataSet.Designers.cs` at the following code

```
public ProductCardRow this[int index] {
    get {
        return ((ProductCardRow)(this.Rows[index]));//here
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint just after the entry of the foreach and the `DataRow r` has correct values as well so idk what is the problem? as for the "`this.Rows[index]`"it showed that the rows count is 0.

I just wanted to create an instance of my custom component whenever a new Product is added.

[I tried changing the Syntax here and it showed the correct ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg9wP.png)

[But It still shows the same error and shows that the rows are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRiwi.png)